# allow a 'selected' option to trigger data entry into one form filed to another

Tags: html

i have a select option item in my form

the ser can pick 1,2, or 3.

two other fields have calculations and a text result

what i am looking for is when the user selects '1', that triggers data in the form to fill into another field designed to receive it

example

field A= 100
Field B= 200
field C is blank awaiting input

Select option 1 -> copy contents of 'A' into 'C'

Select option 2 -> copy contents of 'B' into 'C'

i have spent hours and hours looking for the code to do this. i thought i would ask

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

its quite simple. call a javascript function on the onchange event of your select like this

```
<form name='form'>
<select name='myselect' onchange='changevalue(this.value);'>
<option vlaue='1'>1</option>
<option vlaue='2'>2</option>
<option vlaue='3'>3</option>
</select>
<input type='text' name='A' value='100'>
<input type='text' name='B' value='200'>
<input type='text' name='C'>
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function changevalue(val)
{
if(val==100)
document.form.C.value=document.form.A.value;
if(val==200)
document.form.C.value=document.form.B.value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('targetElem').change(function() {
  //Handle This.
});
```

For Reference check out http://api.jquery.com/change/